# Eclipse becomes unresponsive

Tags: java, eclipse, out-of-memory

I m using Eclipse Indigo. It becomes unresponsive often and finally prompts saying out of memory error and asks me to exit workbench. I increased the Perm Gen space as told in one of the eclipse forums by editing my eclipse.ini file.

Eclipse.ini file contents now is as below,

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-vm C:/Java/jdk1.5.0_15
```

I mostly do Javascript development in eclipse. And I am not able to edit JS file in eclipse.
What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the exact error message that you get?

Comment: !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2013-10-09 14:16:06.115
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Requesting JavaScript AST from selection".
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: This means you ran out of Heap, not PermGen. Increase -Xmx.

Answer (score 1):

Currently maximum only 512MB is allowed for eclipse in your ini (-Xmx512m), if you have enough RAM you shall try increasing it to 1GB. More info here http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F

Answer (score 1):

This problem may be due to

1. You are using old java version , You need to upgrade it with new version
2. If your operation system is 64 bit make sure that you are using 64bit java

Answer (score 1):

Java 5 is pretty old. The GC (and overall optimizations) are slow, outdated and patch level 15 means you're missing many critical bug fixes.

The first step would be to install Java 7 (lastest version). [Make sure you disable the browser plugin because of the security risks](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/disable_browser.xml).

Then make sure that Eclipse uses it: Update the path after `-vm`. Note: If your path contains spaces, use this:

```
-vm
c:\Program Files\Java\...
```

(i.e. put the path into a line of it's own).

Lastly, there are two kinds of memory in Java. Heap and PermGen. The error message tells you which one ran out. Use `-Xmx` to set heap memory and `-XX:MaxPermSize=` for PermGen. 256m PermGen should be enough but some script languages need more.

With Java 7, enable GC1 which should give you better performance: `-XX:+UseG1GC`